# How to make histogram bar outlines transparent in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to have a little bit of space between the bars of a histogram. The simplest way to do this, I think, is to make the outlines of the bars transparent. But I'm not sure how this can be achieved.

Of course, I can have the outline be the same color as the background. This works for the most part, but it's not quite what I want. Note that the (white) outline cuts through the horizontal gridlines, which I would like to see continue between the bars.

Things I tried that don't work:

1. Using `color = NA`. This does not change the appearance of the histogram.
2. Using `alpha = .5`. This affects the fill property but not the color property.

```
library(tidyverse)
theme_set(theme_bw())

ChickWeight %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = weight)) +
  geom_histogram(fill = "lightblue", color = "white")
```

[image: histogram]

Comment: `color="#00000000"`, you can use hexcode and add two characters for transparency, here `00` for full transparent.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it does not appear to work. Could you try and see if it works on your end using my code plus your suggestion?

Comment: Including outlines doesn't reduce the space occupied by each histogram bar (which are, by design, positioned next to one another with no break in between). Setting outlines transparent would have the same effect as not specifying them at all. If you want to include space between bars, you may want to cut the data into bins yourself (or use `layer_data()` on the ggplot object created with a `geom_histogram` layer) & use that dataset with `geom_bar` / `geom_col` instead.